# How to add multiple lines to git commit messages

Tags: git

How do I add multi-line messages using

```
git commit -a -m "..."
```

The answer from this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075783/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-command-line-on-windows) appears to work (judging by the upvotes and acceptance), but it seems a bit cumbersome<sup>1</sup>.

The git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) reads:

> **-m <msg>
>
>   --message=<msg>**
>
> Use the given <msg> as the commit message. If multiple -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.

So, would it be advisable to just use a new `-m` for each new line of the message? Or do "paragraphs" add additional line spacings?

It would be nice if future versions of the command would allow us to just add `\n` between sentences, to denote line breaks.

<sup>1</sup> The linked answer basically advises to use a message template file, and direct git to use the file via `git commit -t <template_file>`

Comment: See some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24587262/4276832).  Basically, it seems like if you omit the `-m` entirely, your default editor (vim, nano, etc.) will open and you can enter however many lines of commit message you want.

Comment: If you omit the `-m`, your favorite editer will open wich will allow you to type a muti line commit message.

Comment: @bsinky  Thanks, I do know about omitting `-m` to add the messages in the editor. I was wondering if there was a simple solution to do it straight from the command line.

Comment: In addition to omitting `-m`, you can also start your message with a `"` and then just hit `enter`. The message will continue across newlines until you terminate with another `"`

Example:

```
git commit -m "line1
line2
line3"
```

Comment: @torbinsky - *if* they are using bash, that is true.  Not if they are using CMD on windows, for example.  This is shell-specific behavior.  (But it is also the approach I point out in my answer, because bash is definitely a good shell to use for command-line git operations.)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Agreed. I tested your answer on both (bash and Windows cmd), and it only worked in the bash shell. I don't think this convenience is enough to get me to start using the bash shell on Windows. When I need linuxy stuff, I use a VM.  On Windows, I use Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add line break to 'git commit -m' from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064563/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-the-command-line)

Comment: I answered this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645586/6839738

Comment: try this: ```git commit -m "line 1 comment" -m "line 2 comment" ```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer may depend on what shell you use to run git.  For example with bash (just tested this on windows using the bash shell installed with git):

```
git commit -m "this is
a multi-line
message"
```

because quite simply bash will not assume that hitting return ends the command if it's in the middle of a quoted string.

That said, I've only ever used `-m` for one-line messages; other options just "make more sense" to me if I need a multi-line message.

Comment: I am on Windows. Just tested it with git bash shell, and it worked as advertised (+1). Unfortunately, I never use the bash shell. It's overkill for me, and I can't then use all of my batch scripts. I also tested it from a Windows command prompt and (as you assumed) it doesn't work there unfortunately.

Comment: It seems that Powershell on Windows will let you enter multi-line messages in this way.

Answer (score -3):

use the following commands

1. git commit
2. ctrl+c
3. Press I
4. Type multi line comment
5. Press ctrl+c
6. :wq